# How to pass parameter from ajax to thymeleaf and Spring

Tags: java, ajax, spring, thymeleaf, dropdown

I'm working on a project and I'm trying to do a cascade dropdown using ajax.

I managed to do the implementation but I don't know how to pass the selected id from the second dropdown to a controller using thymeleaf in order to show the information about the selected airport.

So, this is the script:

```
function retrieveAirports() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/countries/airports?countryId=' + $('#countrySelect option:selected').val(),
            type: 'get',
            contentType: 'application/json',

            success: function (result) {
                var $dropdown = $("#airportSelect");
                var $id = $("#airportId");
                $dropdown.empty();
                $.each(result, function() {
                    $dropdown.append($("<option/>").val(this.id).text(this.name));

                });
            },
            error: function () {
                // what do you want to do in case of error
            }
        });
    }
```

And this is the implementation of the dropdown. First, we have the country dropdown

```
<select id="countrySelect" onchange="retrieveAirports()">
    <option selected value="-1"></option>
    <option th:each="country : ${countries}" th:value="${country.id}" th:text="${country.name}">Option</option>
</select>
```

And this one is the airport dropdown, the result of this one depends on the id that was passed from the first one to the script.

```
<form th:action="@{/airport}" method="post" th:object="${airportSelect}">
    <select id="airportSelect">
        <option selected value="-1"></option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

Can someone please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Note that your REST URLs don't follow convention; you would have either `/countries/{code}/airports` (if "countries" is part of the path) or `/airports?country={code}` (if it's just a filter on "airports").

Answer (score 0):

Add a `name` to the airport selector, for example `airport`:

```
<form th:action="@{/airport}" method="post" th:object="${airportSelect}">
    <select id="airportSelect" name="airport">
        <option selected value="-1"></option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

And then, when you click the submit button, the Spring controller for the path `/airport` will be called with `airport` as a POST parameter. For example:

```
@Controller
public class AirportController {
  
  @PostMapping("/airport")
  public View viewAirport(@RequestParam("airport") int airport) {
    // ...
  }

}
```